# Infragistics, Net Advantage 10.3 Windows Forms, Help documentation?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, netadvantage

I've recently been looking around at some software that's been on the computers for a long time and came across this one, its all installed and works fine but I can't seem to find any useful documentation on how to use it, there seems to be very little help out there to explain how to make each tool work etc., there is obviously their web page and their help files and forums but I've browsed these for hours to no avail, I was wondering if anyone else had experience with these tools and could either give some pointers or knows where I can find some half decent documentation.

Thanks in advance,

Rhys

Comment: Oh, well there was an answer here i was about to mark as correct but it got deleted :S none the less the link on it was exactly the documentation i needed and i nabbed it before the post went, whoever it was thankyou, its just what  i needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are links to the current NetAdvantage documentation from the [Online Help Documentation](http://www.infragistics.com/support/documentation.aspx#OnlineDocumentation) page.  2010 Volume 3 is still available online now though will likely be removed after the release of 2012 Volume 1.

For older volumes , you can reference the newer documentation as the features that existed in earlier volumes will still be included in the current documentation.  The only difference is that the new features wouldn't apply to you.

You could also install the help locally.  To get the download you would need to have a key registered to your profile on the Infragistics website and then the downloads would be available from the [My Keys and Downloads](https://www.infragistics.com/Membership/Default.aspx?panel=Downloads) page.